# Proper Procedure for Extracting MQ Sensors from Breakout Boards

Tags: sensor, soldering

I'm working on a sensor array project using MQ-2,3,4,5,6,8, and 135 sensors. The bulky breakout boards would unnecessarily increase the PCB size, and purchasing bare sensors is not a cost-effective option. How can I safely remove these sensors from their breakout boards without compromising their sensitivity?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure buying bare sensors is not cost effective? You can buy them for around 5 € each. Even if you get boards for free, how many you can remove per hour? You are undervaluing your time.

Comment: I'm in the Philippines, and I found all the sensors I need in a single shop based on China on Shopee.ph. The total cost is 387 PHP, plus 40 PHP for shipping. Since it's for a university project, I only need one unit of each sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solder sucker is the way to go for desoldering through-hole components. I recommend [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002MJMXD4) specifically, personally.

While solder wick (aka solder braid) can be used, it's generally more suited for desoldering surface-mount components--it can have trouble wicking the solder out of a through-hole.

Another option is a desoldering station, which is basically a soldering iron combined with a vacuum pump. That's more expensive than just using a solder sucker with your existing iron, though. Hot air can also work, but you run the risk of damaging what you're trying to desolder, if it's temperature sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the soldering iron vacuum pump tip, Hearth. I've checked out the YIHUA 929D-V priced at around 300 PHP, and it seems to suit my future desoldering needs. I own a separate vacuum pump, but I've struggled with that method, which is why I decided to give this a try. I'll be testing it on an extra MQ sensor for practice, and I'm also curious about @MiNiMe's copper wire method. Appreciate the help from both of you!

Comment: The desoldering station is the professional option for removing through-hole parts. These hand pumps have diverse quality and may often lead to excessive heating of the part - same thing with solder wick.

Comment: @Lundin Which is why I recommend a specific one that I know to be good quality. A desoldering station is substantially more expensive, so it's not my first recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with solder braid or a desolder gun or a hot air soldering station.

[Solder braid](https://hakko.com.sg/blogs/tune-in-with-hakko/effective-solder-removal-with-desoldering-wire) is used together with a solder iron, see link.

A [desolder gun](https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/metcal/mx-uk5/metcal-soldering-accessory-desoldering-iron-kit-mx/8600162) have a hollow tip that is put over the pin, and when solder have melted, it's sucked away with vacuum. The gun in the link uses compressed air through a nozzle that creates vacuum (Bernoulli's principle). Hakkos models uses a vacuum pump instead.

And finally, a hot air soldering / rework station, uses hot air. It's effective, both to de-/solder and to overheat components.

But there's one more way to do it, and that's with a thick copper wire. Bend it to the outer shape of the sensors pins, make sure it's not tight. Connect each and every pin to the wire with solder, and now heat the middle of the wire. A component usually drops from the PCB by it's own weight (take care if the sensor is sensitive to shocks), or it can be wiggled out.

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Like describe how this would be done?

Comment: Hakkos desoldering stations are also pretty crappy in my experience. We used one in production but there were always problems and constant cleaning/maintenance. Hakko aren't even close to playing in the same league as Metcal.

Comment: @Lundin Then you know more then I do, I've only seen them in some repair videos so it seemed valid to include Hakko, and that's it. I wouldn't trade my old Metcal station for anything else.

Comment: I've used both Metcal and Hakko, desoldering stations as well as regular irons. It's an huge difference in quality. Metcal is state of the art and Hakko is mediocre.